# How to fix java.util.MissingResourceException in Mqtt v5

Tags: android, mqtt, paho

I am implementing a mqtt broker connection in my kotlin android app using this version of paho mqtt library

```
implementation 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client:1.2.5'
```

base on my research the following progaurd rule is suposed to fix the issue

```
-keep class org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.** {*;}
-keep class org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.*$* { *; }
-keep class org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.logging.JSR47Logger { *; }
```

But this does not work for the v5 library. Whenever i run my app it crashes and throws this error

```
Process: com.sckooly.net, 
PID: 7438 java.util.MissingResourceException: 
Error locating the logging class at wb.b.a(SourceFile:27) 
at vb.b.<init>(Unknown Source:5) at at com.sckooly.net.chat.MosquittoManager.startSubscriber(Unknown Source:27) 
at com.sckooly.net.activities.HomeActivity$onCreate$1$1.invokeSuspend(SourceFile:62) 
at oa.a.resumeWith(Unknown Source:8) at bb.g0.run(Unknown Source:104)
```